# Unable to access tags in API data.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've successfully accessed data from a request to an API.

I have set the data as a var `weatherData`

If I print out weatherData, I get this whole blob here.

> {"coord":{"lon":-79.42,"lat":43.7},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50n"},{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":286.46,"pressure":1006,"humidity":100,"temp_min":285.15,"temp_max":288.15},"visibility":1207,"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":240},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1509943080,"sys":{"type":1,"id":3721,"message":0.1665,"country":"CA","sunrise":1509969642,"sunset":1510005682},"id":6167865,**"name":"Toronto"**,"cod":200}

The city is what I'm interested in. 
I've tried accessing it with weatherData.name but it returns as undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(weatherData)`

Comment: @AngYC That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a little add on, incase you can't figure out the return result is JSON or string, this will always be a good snippet to use (In fact I include it on all my projects)

It will try to parse as a JSON and if it failed, it will return `undefined`.

```js
function tryJSON(x) {
    try {
        x = JSON.parse(x);
    } catch (e) {}

    if ((!!x) && (x.constructor === Object)) {
        return x;
    }
}

console.log(tryJSON('{ "apple": 10 }'));
console.log(tryJSON("{ :notJSON }"));
console.log(tryJSON({ orange: 5 }));
```